# Windows phone user control change pivot selecteditem

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls, pivot

I created my own UserControl, I added Button to it. Also I have Pivot where I added this UserControl. How can I change Pivot selecteditem in Button_Click event in my UserControl.

Binding:

```
        Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex");
        binding.Source = historyControls[i].SelectedIndex;
        Pivot_Second.SetBinding(Pivot.SelectedIndexProperty, binding);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Button_Click()
{
   SelectedIndex = desiredindex;
}
```

Make a property

```
private int _SelectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
  get
  {
    return _SelectedIndex;
  }
  set
  {
    _SelectedIndex = value;
    RaisedPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
  }
}
```

then bind this property with selected index of your pivot.

I hope it will work.

Comment: Can you give an example, how can I bind Pivot.SelectedIndex, and Control.SelectedIndex? I add in edit how I tried it.